# Netsuite Data Extraction to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, netsuite

I need to export some tables of netsuite to mssql. How can i get the table structure and will insert that data to mssql . I need to use this data for my analytics tool. Can anybody help me on this ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have purchased the SuiteAnalytics Connect bundle from NetSuite, you can download and install their ODBC driver on your SQL server.  Then you can create a linked server directly to your NetSuite instance.

The schema for the views that are exposed via the ODBC driver can be found in the NetSuite help under the topic `SuiteAnalytics -> SunteAnalytics Connect -> Connect Schema`.

We have a set of stored procedures that run nightly downloading our data into SQL server using this feature.

Comment: Where i can found these stored procedures examples? If you have any please share with me?

Comment: Is it possible to push data back into Netsuite using ODBC, or is ODBC used for just moving data from NS to mssql?

Comment: The ODBC connection to NetSuite is read-only so you can only read data, not write data.

Answer (score 1):

We purchased the SuiteAnalytics Connect add-on module for this purpose and got ODBC connection access to our data. It's not cheap, but it does provide pretty good access.  You can do it via SuiteTalk / RESTlets, but you'll have to build your own, unless someone else on here has or knows of something pre-built/written to download data that way.